# how to lift/raise a tkinter button python

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm trying to lift a Tkinter button so it overlaps a scrolltext in tkinter, I've tried
button.lift()
button.tag_raise

and I've also tried to make the other widget I want to be under the button lower by using
widget.lower()
widget.tag_lower()

but none of these seem to work for me, it may be because scrolltext is not a fully official tkinter widget and that may cause issues, but if anyone can help please do so! Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

save_button = Button(main, fg="white",
                        bg="#121212", text="SAVE", font=("Microsoft JHengHei", 10),
                        border=0, activeforeground="white", activebackground="#141414", 
                        relief=FLAT,
                        width=12,
                        command=save_textfile)   
save.pack()

scrolltext = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, height=11, width=60, bg="#050505", fg="white", bd=0)
scrolltext.pack()

#this should lower the scrolltext 
scrolltext.lower()

#and this should lift the save button
save_button.lift()
```

neither of these work.

Comment: Try if you can place the button on the scrolltext using place ()  method

Comment: wow, im actually so blinded, that worked just perfectly ; i just needed to parent the button to scrolltext. thank you!

Comment: No worries !!

Comment: The code you posted will throw an error when run for at least three different reasons.

Comment: yeah sorry, I didn't really check over it, I just needed a quick example.